# Stm32f103 adc stable conversion

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, adc

I am making a ntc thermometer with stm32f103c8 (by writing over registers without using state library). The code works as it is,I did the adc conversion in 7.5 cycles. I used the calibration register and ran the adc in continuous conversion mode.  but it is not fully stable, the value in the last step is constantly changing. How can I make adc more stable?.I want the adc value to stay as constant as possible

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header
#include "math.h"
float heat = 0;
char analog[10];
char analog2[10];
int temp;
int a;
void int2char(int num, char str[])
{
  char lstr[30];
   int cnt = 0;
  int div = 10;
  int j = 0;

    
    
while( num >= div)
{
    lstr[cnt] = num % div + 0x30;
    num /= 10;
    cnt++;
}
    lstr[cnt] = num + 0x30;
for(j= cnt ; j >=0;j--)
{
    str[cnt-j] = lstr[j];
}
   
   
}

void DelayUs(unsigned long t)
{
    for(;t>0;t--)
        {
         SysTick->LOAD = 72;
       SysTick->VAL = 0;
       while((SysTick->CTRL & 0x00010000) == 0);
        }
}


void lcd_cmd(unsigned char data)
{
    //pin_output(0,11);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x100;//lcd_rs(LOW);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x200;//lcd_rw(LOW);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH);
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= (data & 0x00f0);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW);
    
    DelayUs(20);
    
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH);
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= ((data << 4) & 0x00f0);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW);
}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data)
{
    //pin_output(4,7);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x100;//lcd_rs(HIGH);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x200;//lcd_rw(LOW);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH);
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= (data & 0x00f0);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW);
    
    DelayUs(20);
    
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH)
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= ((data << 4) & 0x00f0);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW)
}

void lcd_send( char str[])
{
    int i = 0;
        while(str[i])
        {
            lcd_data(str[i]);
            i++;
            DelayUs(100);
        }

}


void lcd_msg(unsigned char line_1_2, unsigned char pos_0_16, char msg[])
{
    short pos = 0;
    if(line_1_2==1)
    {
        pos = 0;
    }
    else if(line_1_2==2)
    {
        pos = 0x40;
    }
    lcd_cmd(0x80 +pos + pos_0_16);
    DelayUs(100);
    lcd_send(msg);
}



int main(void)
{
    // initialize the delay function (Must initialize)
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0x00FFFFFF;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    SysTick->CTRL = 5;
    
    
    //pin_output(4,11);
    RCC->APB2ENR = 0x04; /// port a active
    GPIOA->CRL   = 0x33330000; /// pin a4-a7 
    GPIOA->CRH   = 0x00003333; /// pin a8-a11

    DelayUs(20000);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x100;//lcd_rs(LOW);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x200;//lcd_rw(LOW);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH);
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= 0x30; // 8 bit communication mode 
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW);
    
    DelayUs(20000);
    
    
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x100;//lcd_rs(LOW);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x200;//lcd_rw(LOW);
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR |=0x400;//lcd_e(HIGH);
    DelayUs(5);
    GPIOA->ODR &= 0xff0f;
    GPIOA->ODR |= 0x20; // 4 bit communication mode 
    DelayUs(10);
    GPIOA->ODR &=~0x400;//lcd_e(LOW);
    
    
    lcd_cmd(0x2C); // 4 bit communication mode / 2 lines
    DelayUs(5000);
    lcd_cmd(0x0C); // Display ON
    DelayUs(5000);
    lcd_cmd(0x01); // Clear Display
    DelayUs(5000);
    lcd_cmd(0x02); // Get back to initial address
    DelayUs(5000);
    
        lcd_msg(1, 0,"Temp(C)");
        RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x201; //ADC 1 interface clock enable
        ADC1->SQR3 = 2;  //first transformation in regular order   
        ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(0xf << 20);//adc channel string length          
    ADC1->SMPR2 |= (0x1);   //7.5 loop
    //12mhz: 7.5+12.5 =20 hz ->3.3us(micro s) 
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1 << 11); // right alignment     
    ADC1->CR2 |= 2|1; //adc on and continuous
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<3);// reset calibration 
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<2);// calibration  
    ADC1->CR2 |=1; //adc on 
    while(1)
    {
  heat = log(((40950000 / ADC1->DR) - 10000));
  heat = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * heat * heat)) * heat);
  temp = (heat - 273.15)*100; 
     int2char(temp,analog);
     lcd_msg(2, 2,analog);
        if(temp<1000)
        {
         a=3;   
        }
        else if(temp<10000)
        {
     a=4;
        }
    else
        {
     a=5;
        }           
     temp=temp%100;
     int2char(temp,analog2);
     lcd_msg(2, a,".");
     lcd_msg(2, a+1,analog2);
     lcd_msg(2, a+3,"     ");
     DelayUs(250000);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are probably better of asking this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. You are looking for a stable reference voltage, low noise from thermometer, averaging samples etc.

Comment: Also see *How to get the best ADC accuracy in STM32 microcontrollers* (https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00211314-how-to-get-the-best-adc-accuracy-in-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)